# PySNMP get specific entry

Tags: python, pysnmp

I am trying to `GET` a specific value using PySNMP.

Below is a short example of walking `dot1dTpFdbAddress`:

```
    ...
    11: dot1dTpFdbAddress.104.247.40.225.176.200 68:f7:28:e1:b0:c8
    12: dot1dTpFdbAddress.104.247.40.226.148.111 68:f7:28:e2:94:6f
    13: dot1dTpFdbAddress.104.247.40.226.158.32 68:f7:28:e2:9e:20
    14: dot1dTpFdbAddress.104.247.40.226.160.73 68:f7:28:e2:a0:49
    ....
```

Now I want to use PySNMP to get the following entry:

`14: dot1dTpFdbAddress.104.247.40.226.160.73 68:f7:28:e2:a0:49`

This is my current code:
`...@110` is needed to get the entries in VLAN 110.

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = cmdGen.getCmd(
    cmdgen.UsmUserData('commro@110'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('SWITCH1', 161)),
    cmdgen.MibVariable('BRIDGE-MIB', 'dot1dTpFdbAddress', '68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'),
    lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
)

# Check for errors and print out results
if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
else:
    if errorStatus:
        print('%s at %s' % (
            errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex)-1] or '?'
            )
        )
    else:
        for name, val in varBinds:
            print('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
```

But it returns the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" C:/scripts/git/AYIT/network/snmp_portinfo/portsec.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 29, in __call__
    self._testValue(value, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 108, in _testValue
    raise error.ValueConstraintError(value)
pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: b'68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 29, in __call__
    self._testValue(value, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 183, in _testValue
    v(value, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6) failed at: "b'68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\base.py", line 30, in _verifySubtypeSpec
    self._subtypeSpec(value, idx)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535)), ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6) failed at: "b'68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'""

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 500, in resolveWithMib
  File "<string>", line 1172, in getInstIdFromIndices
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\proto\rfc1902.py", line 195, in clone
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\univ.py", line 328, in clone
    value, tagSet, subtypeSpec, encoding, binValue, hexValue
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\univ.py", line 312, in __init__
    base.AbstractSimpleAsn1Item.__init__(self, value, tagSet, subtypeSpec)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\base.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._verifySubtypeSpec(value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\base.py", line 33, in _verifySubtypeSpec
    raise c('%s at %s' % (i, self.__class__.__name__))
pyasn1.type.error.ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535)), ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6) failed at: "b'68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'"" at MacAddress

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/scripts/git/AYIT/network/snmp_portinfo/portsec.py", line 9, in <module>
    lookupNames=True, lookupValues=True
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\entity\rfc3413\oneliner\cmdgen.py", line 181, in getCmd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\sync\cmdgen.py", line 107, in getCmd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\asyncore\cmdgen.py", line 127, in getCmd
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\hlapi\varbinds.py", line 36, in makeVarBinds
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 838, in resolveWithMib
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pysnmp-4.3.2-py3.5.egg\pysnmp\smi\rfc1902.py", line 504, in resolveWithMib
pysnmp.smi.error.SmiError: Instance index ('68:f7:28:e2:a0:49',) to OID convertion failure at object 'dot1dTpFdbAddress': ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535)), ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(6, 6) failed at: "b'68:f7:28:e2:a0:49'"" at MacAddress
```

How can I make this work? Do I need to somehow convert the MAC to an `OCTET STRING`?

Answer (score 0):

That should work with [pysnmp 4.3.3](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp.git).